# What does a sysadmin need to know about Mercurial, e.g. which ports does it use?

Tags: mercurial, hosting, web-hosting

I've asked my webhosting company to install Mercurial so that when I SSH into my website to make changes, I can submit the files directly to version control at Google code.

The support guy is asking me for "all the details" including which ports it uses so they can see if it fits with their security policy.

How do I find out what ports it uses, and what else might they need to know?

Comment: This is most definitely not off topic. The FAQ states the following is a valid question: software tools commonly used by programmers. Mercurial fits the bill 100%. Just because the question errs on sysadmin work, does not mean it *has* to be asked at serverfault. Turns out the answer does not necessarily involve sysadmin work anyway, just knowledge of how the tool works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to run a server at all for Mercurial.  Your sysadmin just needs to make sure you have ssh access to the machine and that the Mercurial executable 'hg' is in your user's path.  If they won't help on that last part you can always do it yourself putting `hg` in your own path.  The URLs to which you'll push will look like:

```
  ssh://yourusername@thesystem/path/in/your/homedir
```

Comment: Oh, so it will use the same port as SSH to connect to the remote repository? Yes, I expected them to install the hg client.

Comment: It's not that it uses the same port -- it actually uses ssh.  It essentially logs in through ssh, runs a shell command to bring up a single use server, uses that, and then exits.  There is no (necessary) long running server as your sysadmin is imagining.  You probably don't need to talk to your sysadmin about this at all.

Comment: You absolutely do not have to talk to their sysadmin at all. You have ssh access already. Which means that once mercurial is available (you can wget and install locally from the webserver), you can push and pull via the ssh protocol. That also means, making changes on your local machine, pushing to google code, sshing to your webserver, and pulling from google code. Much nicer than editing directly on the webserver.

Comment: @Ry4an The question mentions google code, which afaik does **not** provide ssh access, only https (for push).

Comment: @Tonfa, ah, I read that wrong.  If he just wants to push from a shell at his hosting company it's near certain they don't need to set anything up.  I can't imagine they're blocking outbound 443.

Comment: I ended up using svn: I just copied over the binary for the correct linux distro, copied a few required libs and it worked perfectly!